# WP Bakery Page Builder loses settings in Role Manager

Tags: wordpress, visual-composer

We are using WP Bakery Page Builder on for a client website. The plugin works fine, but sometimes the settings in Role Manager, for what post types the composer should be on just resets.

We are researching the possibility to hack the settings programmatically to set it to On be default.

Just wanted to check if anyone else have noticed this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found this on another thread, which recommended adding this to your theme's custom code:

```
<script>$vc_list = array( ‘page’, ‘post’ ); vc_editor_set_post_types( $vc_list );
</script>
```

Comment: Can't see how that could hook into to the settings... will have to research it a bit! Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

This is a bug in older versions. The developers posted a fix for it here:
https://codecanyon.net/item/visual-composer-page-builder-for-wordpress/242431/comments?utf8=%E2%9C%93&term=add_custom_post_type_here&from_buyers_and_authors_only=0

```
<?php
/*
    You can set the post type for which the editor should be
    available by adding the following code to functions.php:
*/
add_action( 'vc_before_init', 'Use_wpBakery' );
function Use_wpBakery() {
  $vc_list = array('page','capabilities','add_custom_post_type_here');
  vc_set_default_editor_post_types($vc_list);
  vc_editor_set_post_types($vc_list);
}
```

Edit: Updated link to dev comment.